# Comment out some chunks/part of Rmd file

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

Is it possible to comment out part of a Rmd file which includes more than one chunk (eg: 4-5)? Regular [HTML comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17047124/4836511) did not work.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "author"
date: "5 August 2017"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
print(123)
```

```{r}
2**2
```
<!-- 
# Comment section starts

This text is not visible in the output.

```{r}
a <- 3*4
a
```
This text not be visible in the output.

# Comment section ends
-->

```{r}
print(1)
```
````

In the past, I remember reading somewhere in the SO posts that it is aimed in the next version of `knitr`.

Update: I am not looking for the solution to use `eval=FALSE` in every chunk as I need to comment out the text in between the chunks as well. Also, I am looking for an elegant way to do this.

The above code outputs pdf output as below:

[image]

Surprisingly, it works. But the same HTML comments (`<!-- -->`) does not work in another original `Rmarkdown` script. The part of skipping part of Rmd file is only achieved after including the below snippet surrounding the code I want to skip executing.

````
<!-- 
# Comment section starts

```{r, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval= FALSE)
```

This is added to the end of the comment:
  ```{r, include=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval= TRUE)
```
-->
````

Could some one explain to me what is the issue in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to comment out R code blocks in R markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058460/how-to-comment-out-r-code-blocks-in-r-markdown)

Comment: This is not possible at least for now. More info: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/974 and https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1363

Comment: Thanks Yihui for the update. Could you please have a look at the updated example? Should I check `knitr::opts_chunk` or other versions in both the scripts?

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to post an updated answer to this as things have changed in newer versions. The html comments `<!-- -->` now achieve this. So everything between the html comment tags will not be run or included in the knitted document.

````
---
  title: "Untitled"
author: "author"
date: "5 August 2017"
output: pdf_document
---

  ```{r}
print(123)
```

```{r}
2**2
```
<!-- 
  # Comment section starts

  This text is not visible in the output.

```{r}
a <- 3*4
a
```
This text not be visible in the output.

# Comment section ends
-->

  ```{r}
print(1)
```
````